# Python flask with multi modules application OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, blueprint

I have been learning python recently and practiced a couple of tutorials and its been going fine, till I have divided my application to sub modules to make it easier to maintain using blueprints, after doing so the application crashed and throw the following error: OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table, here is how im dividing my application:

```
-instance
  -flask.cfg
-app
  - static  // Folder for css
  - templates // Folder for common html files
  -__init__.py // to init the app 
  -module1
    -__init__.py // to register module blueprint
    -subModule1
      -subModule1 Group1
        -templates
          -htmls files
        -__init__.py file //to register group1 blueprint
        -Group1Form
        -Group1Model
        -Group1View
      -subModule1 Group2
        -templates
          -htmls files
        -__init__.py file //to register group2 blueprint
        -Group2Form
        -Group2Model
        -Group2View
    -subModule2
        ....
-main.py
```

The application run fine when I use `flask run` but I have an issue when I use `db.session.add()` method with the exception that the table was not found. I have tried many solutions to this issue but no luck. here is some links for the same issue:

[OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33784212/operationalerror-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table-user)

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/

[Python sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126140/python-sqlite3-operationalerror-no-such-table)

['No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540664/no-application-found-either-work-inside-a-view-function-or-push-an-application)

Here is the flask.cfg file:

```
import os

BASEDIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
DEBUG = True
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.abspath('app.db')
```

And here is how I am initializing the app in the main `__init__.py` file:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
    initialize_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)

def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)
    initialize_extensions(app)
    register_blueprints(app)
    return app

def initialize_extensions(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    with app.app_context():
        db.create_all()

def register_blueprints(app):
    from app.module1.config.university import university_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(university_blueprint)

    from app.module1.config.department import department_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(department_blueprint)

    from app.module1.authors.author import author_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(author_blueprint)

    from app.module1.authors.publications import    publications_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(publications_blueprint)
```

Answer (score 0):

can you move db.init_app() inside app.app_context() function

```
    with app.app_context():
        db.init_app()
```

Comment: you initiated ur database already right, and u have the file .db in your project structure

Comment: I have solved it by adding  with app.app_context(): db.create_all() after registring my blueprints

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue, I was suppose to place:

`with app.app_context():
       db.create_all()`

after registering the blueprints